# Angular 2: Bootstrap Modal is updating the table in background

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a table of students with CRUD operation. For each row I have an Edit button

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead class="studentHeader">
    <tr>
      <td>Roll Number</td>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let student of studentList;let i=index">
      <td>{{student.rollNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{student.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{student.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="editStudent(student)">Edit</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And the modal

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Add Student</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <label path="rollnumber"  class="sr-only">Roll Number</label>
              <input type="text" id="rollNum" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.rollNumber" name="rollnumber" placeholder="Student Roll Number" required autofocus /><br>
              <label path="firstName"  class="sr-only">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="Student First Name" required /><br>
              <label path="lastName"  class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="Student Last Name" required />
              <h5><span class="label label-default">Gender</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.gender">
                <label for="male">Male</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.gender">
                <label for="female">Female</label><br>
              </h5>
 </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="addStudent(studentObj)" *ngIf="studentAdd">Add</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" *ngIf="studentUpdate" (click)="updateStudent(studentObj)">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the component part

```
private studentList: Array<StudentDto> = [];
  private studentObj: StudentDto = {};
  private studentAdd: boolean = true;
  private studentUpdate: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentList = StudentData;
  }

  private addStudent(addStudentObj: StudentDto): void {
    this.studentList.push(addStudentObj);
  }

  private editStudent(editStudentObj: StudentDto): void {
    this.studentAdd = false;
    this.studentUpdate = true;
    this.studentObj = editStudentObj;
  }

  private updateStudent(updateStudentObj: StudentDto): void {
    console.log(updateStudentObj)

  }
```

The problem I'm facing is - In Modal when I edit a student field, values get edited in the background table too and it looks weird. This is because I'm updating the same array of objects.

How to restrict this behavior i.e. Same array should get updated but after clicking the update button in Modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two-way data binding. You can prevent this example by sending copy of your student, edit this copy, and if everything is ok, send it and update proper entity then. You have only one level fields, so you don't have to deep copy. You can change your `editStudent` function:

```
  private editStudent(editStudentObj: StudentDto): void {
    this.studentAdd = false;
    this.studentUpdate = true;
    this.studentObj = Object.assign({}, editStudentObj); // passing a copy
  }
```

Then, when you call `updateStudent()` you can find index in list/array when updated user should be stored and just assign new object in place where old object was held.